# Find an upper and a lower triangular matrix $E,\, F$ such that $D=E+F$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$D=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\ p&q&r\\ u&v&w \end{bmatrix}$$ be a matrix on $\mathbb R$. How to find an upper triangular matrix $E$ and a lower triangular matrix $F$ such that $D=E+F$ in these cases :

(1) $E,\,F$ are invertible

(2) $E,\, F$ are not invertible

(3) with $a\ne0$, $E$ is invertible and $F$ is not invertible ?

Could anyone give me some hints ? Thanks.

Comment: Two hints: The eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are precisely the elements of the main diagonal, and a matrix is invertible iff all its eigenvalues are non-zero

Comment: Assume there is a decomposition $D=E+F$, where $E$ is an upper triangular, $F$ is a lower triangular. Can you find some entries of $E$ and $F$?

Comment: @PWang since a matrix is inverted iff its det is nonzero, and det of a triangular matrix is product of all elements on main diagonal, so I guess I'm gonna use that to find some entries of $E,\,F$ for each cases. Is that a nice idea ?

Comment: @PermQi Yes, the two properties you said are all what you need. Write down $E,F$, compare each entry in $D$ and $E+F$ and you will find the form.

Comment: but how about the case (c) ? How can I split the numbers $a,\,q,\,w$ into the pairs of numbers such that $E$ is inverted and $F$ is not inverted ? Since we have no idea if $a,\,q,\, w=0$ or not